# Create Prev Page Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a way to navigate between pages using **Prev** & **Next** buttons. The buttons were made using bootstrap and font-awesome icons, which can been seen here: [Live Example](http://www.friendshipscans.com/reader/read/test/en/0/0/page/1)

The software being used is a [Comic Reader](https://foolcode.github.io/FoOlSlide/)

I've managed to create a **next page** button using the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $chapter->next_page($current_page); ?>" onClick="return nextPage();" >
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="next-page"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</a>
```

How would I go about creating a **prev button** page that works the same way as the current next page does?

I've tried history.goback but that's exactly that, goes back the previous page according to your history.

Thanks a lot,

Edit: Added more details below as an answer

Comment: Don't you have a function `$chapter->prev_page($current_page);` ?

Comment: Depends on *how* you are doing your pagination. If you are simply using page numbers then surely something similar to your current next_page function could be created?

Comment: What does your `next_page` function look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via plain javascript code as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="return prevPage();" >Prev</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function prevPage(){
    //assuming that the current page count will always be at the end of URL
    // /reader/read/test/en/0/0/page/10
    //here current page number is 10
    var currentPage = window.location.pathname.split("page/")[1];
    var currentPage = parseInt(currentPage);
    var prevPage = 1;
    if(currentPage > 1)
        prevPage = currentPage - 1;
    else
        return; //return if we are on 1st page

    window.location.href =  window.location.href.replace(currentPage,prevPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function LoadPage(i){
  $('#page').html(i).attr('page',i);
  href='/pages/'+i+'.php';
  $('#loaded').load(href);
}

$('#next').click(function(){
  var n = parseInt($('#page').attr('page'));
  var m = $('#page').attr('maxpage');
  n++;
  if (n < m) {
    LoadPage(n);
  }
})

$('#prev').click(function(){
  var n = parseInt($('#page').attr('page'));
  n--;
  if (n > 0) {
    LoadPage(n);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev">&lt;&lt;</button>
<span id="page" page="2" maxpage="10">2</span>
<button id="next">&gt;&gt;</button>
<div id="loaded">0</div>
```

Comment: `.load(href);` fails to load unexisting page so nothing happens to div

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the **next_page** function in the chapter model, I was able to create a **prev_page** function using the same format. ***I would like to make sure whether this is the right way of approaching this problem. I'm quite new to PHP.***

**The original next_page function:**

```
 /**
       * Returns the URL for the next page in the same chapter. It's used for
       * page-change in systems that don't support JavaScript.
       *
       * @author  Woxxy
       * @todo  this function has a quite rough method to work, though it saves
       *       lots of calc power. Maybe it can be written more elegantly?
       * @return  string with href to next page
       */

      public function next_page($page, $max = 0)
      {
        if ($max != 0 && $max > $page)
          return $this->next();

        $url = current_url();
        // If the page hasn't been set yet, just add to the URL.
        if (!$post = strpos($url, '/page'))
        {
          return current_url() . 'page/' . ($page + 1);
        }
        // Just remove everything after the page segment and readd it with proper number.
        return substr(current_url(), 0, $post) . '/page/' . ($page + 1);
      }
```

**prev_page:**

```
public function prev_page($page, $max = 0)
  {
    if ($max != 0 && $max > $page)
      return $this->prev();

    $url = current_url();
    // If the page hasn't been set yet, just add to the URL.
    if (!$post = strpos($url, '/page'))
    {
      return current_url() . 'page/' . ($page - 1);
    }
    // Just remove everything after the page segment and readd it with proper number.
    return substr(current_url(), 0, $post) . '/page/' . ($page - 1);
  }
```

After that, I replaced the code for the prev and next page buttons with this one, respectively:

**Prev Page:**

```
 <a href="<?php echo $chapter->prev_page($current_page); ?>">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="next-page"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </a>
```

**Next Page:**

```
 <a href="<?php echo $chapter->next_page($current_page); ?>">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="next-page"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </a>
```

Would this be an acceptable solution? [Working here](http://www.friendshipscans.com/reader/read/test/en/0/0/page/0)

Thanks a lot for the help, guys!